# How to tryCatch the wrong format of input in R?

Tags: r, input, types, format

```
function1 <- function(n) { n^2 }

a <- function(n) {
  tryCatch(function1(n),
    error = function(e) { return(NaN) })
}
```

inputting `a(s)` returns `NaN`

inputting `a(1 1)` returns error: unexpected input in `"a(1 1"`

inputting `a(1_1)` returns error: unexpected input in `"a(1_"`

question: how to return `NaN` as inputting `a(1 1)` or `a(1_1)` ??

Comment: Passing `1 1` to a function cause a syntax error, not a format error. You can't catch a syntax error... (well, actually there are some ways to do that, but I'd really discourage it...)

Comment: what are those ways? why discourage?

Comment: Well, for example if you `eval(parse())` the code piece, you can catch the syntax errors. But it makes no sense returning NaN if you write a wrong piece of code, code has to be correct, code input can be wrong... The question is, how is it possible that you call `a(1 1)` ? If `1 1` it's a user input, why just you don't put it into a string (i.e. `"1 1"`) and then call as.double before doing the square ? Basically any invalid input would be catched in this way... so, in the end, what are you trying to accomplish ?

Comment: The purpose is to check the user's input is correct. Still not so understand the eval(parse()) usage. can the default syntax error message be modified to NaN?

Comment: How does the user input "arrive" between the two parentheses ? Do you simply concatenate the strings `"a("+userinput+")"` ? If so, just do `"a('"+userinput+"')"` change your function code from `n^2` to `as.double(n)^2` ...

Comment: (and of course you should preprocess the userinput by replacing the possible occurrencies of `'` with `\'`)

Comment: Let's make it simple. My question is how can I detect the syntax error of n and "return NaN" when I execute a(n)? for example, a(1 1), a(1_1), a(c c),etc....

Comment: Yes, I got it, but I'm saying it definitely depends on how you manage the user input (Where does userinput come from ? R or another app written in a different code? etc). Also, you CANNOT just let the user be free to insert the code between the two parentheses, you are terribly open to code injection. e.g. userinput = `1);unlink("C:\\",recursive=T` --> `a(1);unlink("C:\\",recursive=T)` this possibly deletes all files inside directory `C:` recursively. BTW, my rushed suggestion of `eval(parse())` maybe not applicable, it really depends on how the userinput is managed and R is called...

Answer (score 1):

Passing in `1 1` to the function is causing the interpreter to error out, not the function call. You need to separate parameters with a `,`, but even then you would get an error since you're not setup to handle multiple parameters. You can call `a(c(1,1))` to pass in a vector (which will work).

`1_1` is not a valid identifier, so you're getting an interpreter error again.